# How to handle any sort of copyright infringement or piracy in the chat room?

Tags: discussion

A member said they used pirated software within the chat. Not the worst thing but perhaps not great. They then mentioned not seeing any rules explicitly saying you can't link to a Torrent file or assist in piracy within the chatroom, and asked if our chat is not like IRC.

As a community do we want such conversations to be allowed in the chat?

Answer (score 8):

Assisting piracy is explicitly forbidden. From the Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service):

> #### [4. Restrictions](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#4Restrictions)
>
> Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security
> encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that
> are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in **any kind of illegal
> activity is expressly prohibited**.

*Linking* to a website intended for unauthorized distribution of something is not okay. *Admitting* you use pirated software isn't breaking any rules, but it's not something I would encourage.

Comment: I'd suggest amending this to our http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-are-the-rules-for-chat

Comment: @Ryan good suggestion, added

Comment: Considering everything that is said in chat is logged, it's surprising that people would want to discuss this...increasing awareness in this sense could probably deter such conversations?